# How to get current user's data from loopback API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback to create an API. So far I've been able to set up all the models that I require. How can we set up these endpoints so that they show the data for only the user that has been logged in?

For example, user A adds some data in the database and user B adds some other data in the database. Now if user A is logged in, I only want to get the data that was added by A. As of now I'm getting all the data present in the database together.

My model JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "IPs",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "identifier": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "IP": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "plugins": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and JS is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(IPs) {



};
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include your JS

Comment: I used the cli to create this. It came empty. Haven't added any functions yet.

Comment: Hi, look for information on the role of $owner

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MaxAlex, I'll look into this. For now I've found a solution but I'm not sure if this would be the correct way. I've defined a relation from the user model, that helps me to fetch the current user data by using the endpoint users/{id}/IPs. Is this a good approach?

Comment: This is roughly what the $owner role does, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `principalId` of the model from `$unauthenticated` to `$owner`

Note from [loopback documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles):

> To qualify a $owner, the target model needs to have a belongsTo relation to the User model (or a model that extends User) and property matching the foreign key of the target model instance.  The check for $owner is performed only for a remote method that has ‘:id’ on the path, for example, GET /api/users/:id.

Comment: I changed it and through the endpoint api/user/{id}/IPs, I get the data for the entered userId. However if I add some other userId, it still gives me the data, which is not desirable. Can you suggest some method to solve this?